# How to find if a signal is connected to anything

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals, slot

Is there a way to tell if a signal is already connected to a function?

i.e I want to see if signals.siSelectionChange is connected to anything

```
signals.siSelectionChange.connect( self.SelAsSiAssets )
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`QObject.receivers`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#receivers) to get the count of connected functions. I used it as follows, in the `closeEvent()` of a QWidget, I use as window:

```
    receiversCount = self.receivers(QtCore.SIGNAL("siSelectionChanged()"))
    if receiversCount > 0:
        self.sigChanged.disconnect()
```

Note that the signature in the argument string must match the real signature.

Comment: No longer works in PyQt5, sadly, see https://github.com/picotech/picosdk-python-examples/issues/2

Comment: Still working under PyQt5 with slightly other syntax:


`receiversCount = self.receivers(self.siSelectionChanged)
if receiversCount > 0:
    self.sigChanged.disconnect()`

Answer (score 8):

Since I tried this with PyQt5 and it appears that there does not exist a `QtCore.SIGNAL`. I tried it with the `isSignalConnected` method of the QObject. An other problem you will face with this option is that there is no `QMetaMethod.fromSignal` in the PyQt5 library.

As result I wrote a `getSignal` function.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QMetaMethod
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject

def getSignal (oObject : QObject, strSignalName : str):
    oMetaObj = oObject.metaObject()
    for i in range (oMetaObj.methodCount()):
        oMetaMethod = oMetaObj.method(i)
        if not oMetaMethod.isValid():
            continue
        if oMetaMethod.methodType () == QMetaMethod.Signal and \
            oMetaMethod.name() == strSignalName:
            return oMetaMethod

    return None


from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class A (QObject):
        sigB = pyqtSignal()
        def __init__ (self):
            super().__init__()

    oA = A ()

    print ("is 'sigB' connected:", oA.isSignalConnected (getSignal(oA, "sigB")))

    oA.sigB.connect (lambda : print("sigB emitted!"))
    oA.sigB.emit()

    print ("is 'sigB' connected:", oA.isSignalConnected (getSignal(oA, "sigB")))
```

Output:

```
is 'sigB' connected: False
sigB emitted!
is 'sigB' connected: True
```

Comment: Well done. At least 3 things here are unsatisfactory: 1) the PyQt5 documentation is wrong (no `fromSignal`), 2) the idea that `disconnect` should throw a `RuntimeError` (or even an `Exception`) when there are no connections makes no sense, 3) I don't understand why so many of these `QObject` methods (e.g. `isSignalConnected`) are instance methods when they should be static methods: inelegant.